# Calculating the sum : $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1n\coth^{-1}(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I wanted to calculate the sum. I think it should be calculated by converting it to define integral. Thanks for help.

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1n\coth^{-1}(n)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is very little to change in my answer to your previous question:

$$\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n}\text{arctanh}\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2k+1) n^{2k+2}}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{\zeta(2k+2)-1}{2k+1} $$
due to the integral representation
$$ \zeta(2k+2)-1 = \frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{e^x(e^x-1)}\,dx $$
can be written as 
$$ \color{red}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{Sih}(x)}{e^x(e^x-1)}\,dx},\qquad \text{Sih}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sinh z}{z}\,dz.$$
The original series can also be written as

$$\color{red}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-3x^2)-\pi x(1-x^2)\cot(\pi x)}{2x^2(1-x^2)}\,dx}$$
due to the ordinary generating function for the sequence $\{\zeta(2k)\}_{k\geq 1}$.

Comment: Good answer +1.

Comment: How has the series been written? As $${\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-3x^2)-\pi x(1-x^2)\cot(\pi x)}{2x^2(1-x^2)}\,dx}$$