# integral ${\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-3x^2)-\pi x(1-x^2)\cot(\pi x)}{2x^2(1-x^2)}\,dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I wanted to calculate or approximate this integral.

$${\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-3x^2)-\pi x(1-x^2)\cot(\pi x)}{2x^2(1-x^2)}\,dx}$$

Comment: i also want many things....

Comment: a numerical method gives $$\approx 0.676565$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Is it possible to get inverse function of the function in the integral?

Comment: The indefinite integral has a closed form so perhaps you can work out your integral by taking some limit from $\epsilon$ to $1-\epsilon$

Comment: Sounds more like "I want others to do my job of calculating or approximating...". Are there any own thoughts, are you sure the integral is convergent, and if you are, why?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: which numerical method?

Comment: @MariannaKalwat: it is relevant to link your previous question, since it clearly is the origin of the actual question.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you very much for explanation. Is it possible to get inverse function of the function in the integral?

Comment: @MariannaKalwat: maybe through Lagrange inversion theorem that is possible, but I won't bet on a pleasant outcome. On the other hand the wanted inverse function is (pointwise) simple to find numerically by Newton's method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can approximate quite nicely the integrand using a $[2,2]$ Padé approximant built around $x=0$. This gives
$$\frac{(1-3x^2)-\pi x(1-x^2)\cot(\pi x)}{2x^2(1-x^2)}\approx\frac{a_0+a_1 x^2}{1+b_1x^2}$$ with
$$a_0=\frac{\pi ^2-6}{6}\qquad a_1=\frac{3150 \pi ^2-420 \pi ^4+20 \pi ^6-\pi ^8}{210 \left(\pi ^4-90\right)}\qquad b_1=-\frac{2 \left(\pi ^6-945\right)}{21 \left(\pi ^4-90\right)}$$ which makes the antiderivative "simple" since
$$\int \frac{a_0+a_1 x^2}{1+b_1x^2}\,dx=\frac{(a_0 b_1-a_1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{b_1} x\right)}{b_1^{3/2}}+\frac{a_1 x}{b_1}$$ SInce $b_1 <0$ the $\tan^{-1}(.)$ will become  $\tanh^{-1}(.)$.

The result of the integral is quite nasty but evaluates $\approx \color{red}{0.676}469$ to be compared with the "exact" value  $\approx \color{red}{0.676565}$ obtained by numerical integration.

**Edit**

The above result can be improved using a $[4,2]$ Padé approximant built around $x=0$. This gives
$$\frac{(1-3x^2)-\pi x(1-x^2)\cot(\pi x)}{2x^2(1-x^2)}\approx\frac{a_0+a_1 x^2+a_2 x^4}{1+b_1x^2}$$ with
$$a_0=\frac{\pi ^2-6}{6}\qquad a_1=\frac{28350 \pi ^2-1890 \pi ^4-180 \pi ^6+18 \pi ^8-\pi ^{10}}{180 \left(\pi
   ^6-945\right)}$$ $$a_2=\frac{198450 \pi ^4-37800 \pi ^6+1890 \pi ^8-\pi ^{12}}{18900 \left(\pi
   ^6-945\right)}\qquad b_1=\frac{9450-\pi ^8}{10 \left(\pi ^6-945\right)}$$ and
$$\int \frac{a_0+a_1 x^2+a_2x^4}{1+b_1x^2}\,dx=\frac{\left(a_0 b_1^2-a_1 b_1+a_2\right) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{b_1} x\right)}{b_1^{5/2}}+\frac{(a_1 b_1-a_2)x}{b_1^2}+\frac{a_2 x^3}{3 b_1}$$ Integration leads to $\approx \color{red}{0.6765}58$ to be compared with the "exact" value  $\approx \color{red}{0.676565}$ obtained by numerical integration.

For sure, the process can be continued using  $[2n,2]$ Padé approximants and get better and better results as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{result} \\
 1 & \color{red} {0.676}4691933 \\
 2 & \color{red} {0.6765}583583 \\
 3 & \color{red} {0.67656}45794 \\
 4 & \color{red} {0.676565}0865 \\
 5 & \color{red} {0.67656513}15 \\
 6 & \color{red} {0.67656513}57 \\
 7 & \color{red} {0.6765651361} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Is there a way to find an exact form, like a series representation?

Answer (score 3):

Given that 
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\zeta(2k) z^{2k} = \frac{1-\pi z\cot(\pi z)}{2}\tag{A}$$
such integral is convergent and it equals $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\text{arctanh}\frac{1}{n}}{n}$, as you already know from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582097/calculating-the-sum-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-coth-1n). In order to approximate
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log(n+1)-\log(n-1)}{2n}\stackrel{\text{SBP}}{=} \sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{\log(n+1)+\log(n)}{2n(n+1)}\tag{B}$$
one may use creative telescoping. The RHS is clearly related to $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n)}{n^2} =-\zeta'(2)$, which on its turn is related to the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant). A simple approximation can be derived from [Simpson's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpsonsRule.html), since $\frac{1}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{1-x^2}-\frac{\pi\cot(\pi x)}{x}$ has an approximately parabolic behaviour on $(-1,1)$, so

$${\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-3x^2)-\pi x(1-x^2)\cot(\pi x)}{2x^2(1-x^2)}\,dx}\approx \frac{29+2\pi^2}{72} = \color{green}{0.676}933\ldots \tag{C}$$